# Как заставить ssh-agent помнить ключ?

Tags: windows, git, ssh-agent

Проблема в следующем: есть два компьютера на Windows 10, один рабочий, другой домашний. На оба в своё время ставил git. Штука в том, что по какой-то причине, на одном из компьютеров что-то не так с ssh-агентом: он не стартует автоматически и не помнит добавленных ключей.
Да, я знаю про гайды наподобие [гитхабовского](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows) и даже когда не знал о них, пытаясь временно решить проблему, добавлял старт и добавление ключа в bashrc, но проблема в том, что такой способ сработает только для работы из терминала. Скажем, если я хочу запустить удаленную сессию с помощью VS Code, он не сможет авторизоваться с помощью ключа.
В то же время, на другом компьютере вообще никаких проблем: без всяких танцев с бубнами внутри bashrc агент замечательно работает, и программы вроде VS Code тоже отлично пользуются ключами. Полагаю, что где-то в своей жизни, я что-то криво сделал на компе, у которого сейчас проблемы, но переустановка git-а с последующим удалением agent.env ничего не дала.
В чем может быть причина проблемы, и как ее решить?